# method 'setSetting:' not defined in plugin

Tags: cordova, settings.bundle

I'm using Cordova 2.7 in my project, and I'm trying to use a plugin "applicationPreferences" https://github.com/sandeep45/phonegap-plugins/blob/be5af18a5106d90ac534083df714314742b8eb2b/iPhone/ApplicationPreferences/

Having managed to set up the settings.bundle and the plugin, I hit this error:

```
ERROR: Method 'setSetting:' not defined in Plugin
```

Having only attempted to set, I would assume that whatever coding issues are preventing this from functioning will also cause the 'getSetting' method to fail too.

The plugin looks like this :

The H file

https://raw.github.com/sandeep45/phonegap-plugins/be5af18a5106d90ac534083df714314742b8eb2b/iPhone/ApplicationPreferences/applicationPreferences.h

The M File

https://raw.github.com/sandeep45/phonegap-plugins/be5af18a5106d90ac534083df714314742b8eb2b/iPhone/ApplicationPreferences/applicationPreferences.m

I'm not great with obj-c, can any one see where the error s being caused, and how I would correct it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misconfigured the config.xml

it was simple really ..

```
<plugin name="applicationPreferences" value="CVDPlugin" />
```

Should have been ...

```
<plugin name="applicationPreferences" value="applicationPreferences" />
```

Adivce to self, Read The Manual !

At least this stands now as a monolith to those who may make the same dumb mistake :D